# How to fix React Hook "useAppContext" cannot be called in a class component Error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to use useContext() inside componentDidMount() function because I need Id Partition inside it but it gave me error :
React Hook "useAppContext" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function ?

```
 class Invhom extends Component {
   
            //...
    
     componentDidMount(){
                
             const {IdPartition,setIdPartition } = useAppContext();  // ... Error
            
                    let value = this.IdPartition;
                  //  console.log(value);
           axios.get('http://localhost:9091/inventaire/select_inventaire');
                  } }
            //...         
            }

//------------------------------context.js----------------------------------------


    export const AppContext = createContext(null);



    export function useAppContext() {
      return useContext(AppContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html :

> Only Call Hooks from React Functions

You can't call Hooks from class components.

As noted in the [FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-i-need-to-rewrite-all-my-class-components), you do not have to rewrite your class components. However, please consider using function components and Hooks for new code.